# How to insert new records into the custom object using Data Loader which has "Master-Detail" relationship with Account?

Tags: custom-object, data-loader, salesforce-id, data, master-detail

I have an Account object and a custom object "B" where Account is Master and "B" is Child. I already have Account data and I am looking for inserting records in "B" using Dataloader. I have a csv file containing "B" fields and since "Id" is required for data loader, I have grabbed an "Account CaseSafeID" from Account object which holds Account IDs and have created a column for this in csv. Also "Account CaseSafeID" is a custom Formula field on Account. I am trying to insert using Dataloader and "Account Name" in my csv maps to "Account" field on custom object "B". However, in mapping stage I am not sure on mapping "Account CaseSafeID" because corresponding field doesn't exist in my object "B". I tried creating external ID and upsert even that didn't work. I tried to remove "Account CaseSafeID" in csv and I end up with an error like "Account: id value of incorrect type:" I am not sure why Dataloader requires Account CaseSafeId when I already have "Account Name" on csv that maps to field "Account" on custom object "B"? Please help me with this.

Comment: Map the Account CasesafeID column in the CSV with B's Account__c column should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Upsert option for this to work. You can read all the details in [000320964](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320964&type=1&mode=1).

> 7. In step 3: 'mapping' drag and drop the Salesforce field with the name syntax [ObjectName]:[ExternalIDField__c] to map it to your Object B file's column containing the External ID values for Object A's records (in our example, the naming syntax [ObjectName] is "Object A" and [ExternalIDField__c] is the API name of object A's External Id field from step 1).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved my problem.